# Integrate second order DE once

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, fluid-dynamics

Given the vorticity equation $$\frac{D \omega}{Dt}=(\omega \cdot \nabla)\textbf{u}+ν\nabla^2ω$$ and $\textbf{u} =  (−αr/2,v(r),αz) $ in cylindrical polars where alpha is positive constant.

Find $\omega = \xi (r) \hat{\textbf z}$. I got it as $$\xi =\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}+\frac vr$$

Use the vorticity equation to show that $\xi(r)$ satisﬁes a second-order ordinary differential equation.

I got it as $$ \frac{\partial ^2 \xi}{\partial r^2}+\frac 1r \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial r}+ \frac{\alpha}{ν} \xi=0$$

Integrate the equation once to derive a ﬁrst-order ordinary differential equation for $\xi (r)$. You may assume that $\xi '(r)$ is ﬁnite as $r→0$.

---

How can you integrate it "once"...

Comment: Check your question, $\zeta$ and $\xi$?

Comment: @IsmailBello sorry fixed now

Comment: In any case the "once" may be related to the fact that $$ \frac{\partial^2\xi}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial r} + \frac{\alpha}{\nu}\xi = 0 $$ may be recast into: $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left( r\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial r} \right) + \frac{\alpha r}{\nu}\xi = 0 $$

Comment: @IsmailBello hmm ok,  the next part says Solve the ordinary differential equation in (b) part (iv) (the part you just done) to obtain ζ(r) in terms of an arbitrary constant. Do we just get rid of the d/dr sign in your answer then just integrate whats left?

Comment: I haven't properly looked at problem, but no I don't think that will be the case. You can try solutions of the form $\xi = A r^B$ for some constants $A, B$ second order form suggests it (Euler's equation i think is what its called). If I am correct you will get two values of B which differ by a sign. so $\xi = A_1 r^B + A_2 r^{-B}$. Then you use the finite condition at the origin to eliminate the $r^{-B}$ term...

Comment: I take it back, not necessarily equal solutions of B (up to a sign). Have a look at these notes by [Paul Dawkin's](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/EulerEquations.aspx)

Comment: @IsmailBello That would be so weird... because we haven't covered those types of DEs in class, or in previous years of undergrad. Could you check if I derived the pde for xi correctly please. Because there must be something funny going on...

Comment: Will do, I will reply on chat since extended discussion in comments are frowned upon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39932/discussion-between-ismail-bello-and-snowman).

Comment: In second order ODE one more variable change may help:
$$ u^{\prime \prime} + u^{\prime} /r + u/r^2 =0 $$ 
has Lam$e^\prime$ solution:
$$ u = A + B/ r $$
with first order integration
$$ u^{ \prime} +  u/r = A/r  $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you are missing the contribution from the $z-$component of the vortex convection term $\mathbb{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbb{\omega},$ which is $-\frac{ \alpha}{2}r \frac{d \xi}{d r}.$

The correct steady-state differential equation is

$$\frac{d^2 \xi}{dr^2}+\frac 1r \frac{d \xi}{dr}+ \frac{\alpha}{ν} \xi= -\frac{\alpha}{2 \nu}r \frac{d \xi}{d r}.$$

This can be written as

$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r \frac{d \xi}{dr} \right) +\frac{\alpha}{2 \nu}r \frac{d \xi}{d r} + \frac{\alpha}{ν} \xi= 0.$$

The key step is to observe that this equation can be recast as

$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r \frac{d \xi}{dr} + \frac{\alpha}{2 \nu}r^2 \xi \right) = 0.$$

Integrate "once" to obtain

$$r \frac{d \xi}{dr} + \frac{\alpha}{2 \nu}r^2 \xi = A,$$

and,

$$\frac{d \xi}{dr} + \frac{\alpha}{2 \nu}r \xi = \frac{A}{r}$$

where  $A$ is an integration constant.

To solve this first-order differential equation, multiply both sides by the integrating factor $\exp\left(\frac{\alpha r^2}{4 \nu} \right)$ to obtain

$$\frac{d}{dr}\left( \exp\left(\frac{\alpha r^2}{4 \nu} \right)\xi \right) = \frac{A}{r}\exp\left(\frac{\alpha r^2}{4 \nu}\right).$$

If we integrate again, the term on the RHS will introduce an exponential integral that is unbounded in the far-field. Hence, we enforce the boundary condition $\xi(r) \to 0$ as $r \to \infty$ by setting $A= 0,$ to obtain the solution

$$\xi(r) = B\exp\left(-\frac{\alpha r^2}{4 \nu}\right),$$

where $B$ is a second integration constant.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but can you look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789806/finding-x-and-y-components-of-navier-stokes I have exam tomorrow and I am now panicking!!

Comment: Are you sure for your first big expression, the $(\alpha /v)\xi$ is not supposed to be $(3 \alpha/2v)\xi$ where the v is viscosity??? I checked like three times...

Comment: I get it from the $(\omega \cdot \nabla ) \textbf u$ term in the equation. This gives $\alpha \xi$ doesn't it? If it is zero, then I cant see why...

Comment: OK. The term $\mathbb{\omega} \cdot \nabla \mathbb{u}$ contributes $\alpha \xi$ --  which you had.  You forgot the contribution from $\mathbb{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbb{\omega}$ which is $-\frac{ \alpha}{2}r \frac{d \xi}{d r}.$

Comment: Remember $\frac{D \mathbb{\omega}}{D t} = \frac{\partial\mathbb{ \omega}}{\partial t} + \mathbb{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbb{\omega}$ and $ \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial t} = 0$ at steady state.

Comment: $(\textbf u \cdot  \nabla ) \omega$ gives $$-\frac{\alpha r}2 \frac 1r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r \xi)=-\frac{\alpha }2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r \xi)=-\frac{\alpha}2 \bigg( \xi + r \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial r} \bigg)$$ what did I do wrong...

Comment: You are mixing up the gradient and the Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates.  $\nabla \xi = \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial r} \mathbb{e}_r + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial \theta} \mathbb{e}_\theta +   \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial z} \mathbb{e}_z$.

Comment: So $\mathbb{u} \cdot \nabla \xi = u_r \frac{d \xi}{d r}$ is all that survives.

Comment: But it depends on what u bracket first. $(\textbf u \cdot \nabla) \omega$ seems to be different to $\textbf u \cdot (\nabla \omega)$

Comment: I am looking at divergence in polars from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates, under del formulae, 3rd row 2nd column

Comment: I don't think so.  You can check Wikipedia article on grad, curl etc in different coordinate systems. Also it's pretty clear that the term I'm adding makes the differential equation solvable by simple integration. This is a known problem called Burger's vortex.

Comment: I know you are right. But it doesn't make sense. If the material derivative in my notes was $\textbf u \cdot (\nabla \omega )$ instead of $(\textbf u \cdot \nabla ) \omega$, then I perfectly see how you get it. But if you take the u dotted with the nabla, then it doesn't work out....

Comment: That's the divergence.  Completely different. Look at 2nd row for gradient. This is just the dot product of velocity with the gradient of vorticity

Comment: So you are saying $\textbf u \cdot \nabla$ is different to $\nabla \cdot \textbf u $?

Comment: Is $\nabla = (\partial / \partial r , (1/r)\partial/ \partial \theta, \partial / \partial z )$??? If it is then it makes sense!!

Comment: That is correct. And a vector function does not commute with that operator